# How to create AWS Cloudwatch metric filter from same IP addresses or email

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Log file which records login success and failures.  I would like to create an alarm which will trigger in the event of high login-fail events from either the same IP address or the same email address.

```
2015-11-08T17:41:29 login-fail 422 test@test.com 85.255.233.189
2015-11-08T17:59:58 login-fail 422 test@test.com 85.255.233.189
2015-11-08T18:17:27 login-success 201 test@test.com 85.255.233.189
```

A filter which counts the number of login-fails is simple:-

```
[datetime, result=login-fail, status, email, ip]
```

but is there a method to enhance the filter to match when either email or IP address is the same within a given period?

Ultimately I'd like to create an alarm that will automatically update the VPC Network ACL to block attacking IP addresses when unusual activity is detected and prevent the web servers from receiving any of the naughty traffic.

Any suggestions or other approaches welcome.